# Как сделать скрипт в Unity позволяющий проверять объект, который столкнулся с триггером?

Tags: c#, unity3d

В C# скрипте триггера в Unity прописан код с выводом в консоль сообщения, если игрок достигнет триггера. Скажите пожалуйста как реализовать условие, которое будет проверять сталкивается ли объект "Player" с триггером "END" или какой другой объект. Нужно для того, чтобы в результате проверки сообщение выводилось только в том случае, если объект это именно "Player", ведь в игре много объектов, которые могут столкнутся с "END". И скажите пожалуйста как нужно было нагуглить этот вопрос. Я новичок в Юнити.

```
    void OnTriggerEnter() 
    {
        Debug.Log("LEVEL WON");
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

К сожелению комментарий оставить не могу.

Создай тег для обьекта "Player", затем создай скрипт для обьекта "END" или используй который висит на нем. В скрипте пропиши:

```
 private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) //Вместо "Player" можно любой тег
    {
        Debug.Log("YourTextHere");
    }
}
```

Любой обьект с тегом "Player" который столкнется с обьектом "END" будет выводить сообщение в консоль.

Comment: Спасибо большое.